# CodeIgniter routes map all URI segments to one controller/method

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have CI app with one controller, 'primary.'

I want to map all requests to the method primary->index() and pass the segments as arguments to the index method.

I've tried setting up a route in config/routes.php:
$route['(:any)'] = "primary/index/$1";

but for some reason this is not working
Ex: (I want)
www.example.com/test/delta ---(routed)---> www.example.com/primary/index/test/deta

Anyone know what I'm missing?

**Figured it out!**
$route['(.*)'] = 'primary/index/$1';
Also I forgot to remove index.php with .htaccess

Comment: you know codeigniter works by routing all requests through `index.php` right? from this you can do your preprocessing in the index script without creating another level of redundant indirection

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

```
$route['(.*)'] = "primary/$1";
```

Comment: I tried that, and it works. Turns out I just forgot to use .htaccess to remove 'index.php' from the url... oops.

Comment: though its not seemed correct but it will output "www.example.com/test" where "test" is your controller method

Comment: actually i just used $route['(.*)'] = 'primary/index/$1'; <-- that works

Comment: I was thinking about the "/index/" thing... i thought of it as "index.php while thinking of .htaccess" so I just posted the controller part.

Answer (score 0):

It's also achievable via [remap](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) on your controller